# Syntax issue with Python and Sqlite using a variable with LIKE %var% command

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having some trouble with the syntax in my script.

This works:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE address LIKE "%Yongsan%"')
```

But, I want the `"%Yongsan%"` to be replaced with a `raw_input` variable and I can't figure out the syntax of the '%' sign.

So, something along the lines of...

```
t = raw_input("Enter your District: ")

g = '%',t,'%',

c.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE address LIKE ?', g)
```

But, when I execute the script I get the following error:

```
"sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. 
The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied."
```

Comment: Yes, thank you that works fine. However, I was told it was better to use ? as a placeholder instead of %s.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should work.

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE address LIKE "%%%s%%"' % (raw_input('Enter your district: '),))
```

If I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do, please tell me.